# Is $f(z)$ complex differentiable at $z_0$ in these strange situations?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been considering what conditions are sufficient to conclude that a complex-valued function $f(z)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ is differentiable at $z_0$. Let $z_0\in \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is some open set. I have been thinking about the following situations. (I am not sure whether it is *possible* for these situations to happen though)

**Situation 1**: Let $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$ be well-defined on $\Omega$, but  satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations only at one point, namely, $z=z_0$. Is $f(z)$ complex differentiable at $z_0$? Is $f(z)$ complex differentiable in some $\epsilon-$ball centered at $z_0$?

**Situation 2**: Let $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$ be well-defined on $\Omega$, but satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations at *all points in $\Omega$ except for $z_0$*. If this situation is possible, what can we say about differentiability of $f(z)$ on $\Omega$?

**Situation 3**: Let $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$ be well-defined and continuous on $\Omega - \{z_0\}$ and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations. Surely $f$ is not differentiable at $z_0$, but is it $f$ differentiable at *any point other than $z_0$*?

Comment: It is a matter of definition : $f(z)$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ means $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists (and doesn't depend on the path $z \to z_0$).  It is equivalent to $f(z)$ is real differentiable at $z_0$ at satisfies the CR equations.
Then,  [$f(z)$ holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) on an open set $U \in \mathbb{C}$ means $f(z)$ is complex differentiable at every $z \in U$

Comment: Finally, you can prove the Cauchy integral theorem and formula for holomorphic functions, as well as [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem), so that $f(z)$ holomorphic on $U \setminus \{z_0\}$ and bounded as $z \to z_0 \implies $ $f(z)$ holomorphic on $U$

Answer (score 2):

(1): false. Consider $f(z) = 0$ on the coordinate axes and the points with both rational coordinates, $f(z) = 1$ otherwise. You can see that
$$u_x(0) = u_y(0) = v_x(0) = v_y(0)$$
but $f$ is *discontinuous* at all the plane!

(2): [Looman–Menchoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem)

> A *continuous* complex-valued function defined in an open set of the complex plane is holomorphic if and only if it satisfies the Cauchy–Riemann equations.

Continuity can be weakened to bondedness (When is a Function that Satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Equations Analytic? by J. D. Gray and S. A. Morris, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 85, No. 4, pp. 246-256).

I *think* that (2) is impossible, but the proof *can* highly nontrivial.

(3): trivially true. Continuous partial derivatives $\implies$ real differentiable; real differentiable $+$ CR $\implies$ complex differentiable.